# Run RViz with configuration file from .launch file

Tags: rviz, roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I was wondering if there is any way you can open rviz from a launch file while openning a custom configuration. The terminal command would be:

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find package_name`/rviz/config_file.rviz
```

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287670/run-rviz-with-configuration-file-from-.launch-file/) by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2018-04-05

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes:

```
<launch>
  <node type="rviz" name="rviz" pkg="rviz" args="-d $(find package_name)/rviz/config_file.rviz" />
</launch>
```

Note that this is the same approach you would use for any program / node that accepts command line arguments. Doing it in a launch file just allows you to use the `find` substitutation command.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 24